# after end of contract difference in hours between client and boss

Tags: contracts, germany

I worked for company A (where I get payed) in IT area until some month ago. My boss had contract with company B which payed for my work per hour. Company B had contract with company C which payed for full products (software). I was sitting in the rooms of company C all the time I worked for them. My hours I have to send to my boss only. I wished to end my contract because my family moved long distance away from jobs location.

Now there are problems between the companies. I will explain how I understand it: my boss (A) wrote invoice to company B but they do not want to pay because they say I needed to much time per product (C).

Additional I could not finish last product, so company C do not want to pay (full payment) for this. (I do not know enough details how they argument, only that they are unhappy I do not finish it)

Now my boss and the contact person of company B separate want me to explain my point of view.

My question: What could follow for me from this? What duty have I after the end of the contract?

Comment: Your contract's over now? Do you have a new job lined up yet?

Comment: Unless you had some weird multi-party contract, all this stuff doesn't matter. What matter is the hours billed to company A by you, the rest is simply not your problem.

Comment: @nick012000 yes my contract is over now. I have no new job until now.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul If there exists something like that I have a "normal standard" employment contract.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I assume I should explain why I spend more time than someone say I have to need. If there where no additional time then the last product is finished (by calculation)

Comment: What standard contact? Not sure I've mentioned anything liked that. But the idea that you are liable for delivery of work between A and anyone would have to be specified in your contact in bold letters. Otherwise the clause would very likely not be enforceable anyway.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul It was a picture for "no, there is no weired multi-party contract".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You personally can't normally be forced to finish the product. What your employer A might offer, is for you to get some extra payment to finish the product. But unless you have it written down in any kind of contract, A has no right to demand your working hours.

If B or C are forced to pay anything at all, or A finds someone else to finish your task (which would take even longer since the newcomer would need to get familiar with what you have done already, and therefore be more costly for B) is none of your business and can only be handled by them.

I have been in a comparable situation. In my case my employer send a new Coworker for free that would replace me once I was gone and for the time my contract was still going on I would teach my succesor.

Comment: I had teached a colleague from company A to do "my" work in office of company C after I am gone.

Comment: In that case B will most likely have to pay for most of your colleagues work then. But as mentioned above those ghosts won't come to haunt you unless you let them :)

Answer (score 3):

> Now my boss and the contact person of company B separate want me to explain my point of view.

I hope you're being paid for that time.

> My question: What could follow for me from this?

Possibly a bad reference. That's it.

> What duty have I after the end of the contract?

Nothing (unless you signed a weird contract promising delivery).

In other words, this is really not your problem, and I really do hope that they're paying you for that extra time (time + travel time).

Definitely, do not let yourself get bullied during that session. If they're not being nice to you, don't be afraid to pick up your things and just walk away.

Or if for any reason, you don't feel comfortable going to that meeting, don't go. No one can force you to do anything you don't want to do.

Furthermore, do not sign anything during that meeting. It's a private disagreement between them, not you. And if they want you to sign something, just take the paper and tell them that you want to show it to your lawyer first.

Answer (score 2):

As i see it, your only responsibility is according to your contract (for example notice period)

If you work per hour with your employer, this is what you should be paid.
To your employer`s customer you have no fiscal obligations.

Customer can always be grumpy regarding the cost of their purchase -
(everyone would like to get everything for free and yesterday) :)

As for going forward, perhaps you can suggest finishing product remotely if it is in any way possible, but i wouldnt recommend it, seems there are some other issues you do not know about between these two